# Comparator of ArrayList<Object> doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, arraylist, comparator

Please help me to solve this problem. I've been trying to write different comparators already and none of them works properly.

They like sort by parts. Let it be values like: `0, 4, 1, 9 , 18, 3, 18, 9.`

And it sorts like this: `9, 9, 0, 1, 3, 18, 18, 4.`

Some "ordered" random I would say.

Please help to find what I did wrong.

Class with data and `Comparator`:

```
public class CoursesData {
private String url;
private String name;
private String lessonsCount;
private String isFree;
private String price;
private String language;
private String difficulty;

private AuthorData author;

public static Comparator<CoursesData> CoursesDataPriceComparator = new Comparator <CoursesData> () {
    public int compare (CoursesData left, CoursesData right){
        return right.getPrice().compareTo(left.getPrice());
    }
};

....(getter-setters)
```

And how I use this comparator:

```
    ArrayList<CoursesData> coursesDatas = parserJson.getCourses();
    Collections.sort(coursesDatas, CoursesData.CoursesDataPriceComparator);
    mAdapter = new CoursesItemAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.catalog_list_item, coursesDatas);
```

Price is String but with digit values. Maybe its the problem...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: *Maybe its the problem*. It actually is. You can use `Integer.parseInt` to  get the actual `int`, and make the comparison between those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
return right.getPrice().compareTo(left.getPrice());
```

with

```
return new Double(right.getPrice().trim()).compareTo(
  new Double(left.getPrice().trim())
);
```

Comment: I would use Double instead of Integer, just to cover all number range.